# Georeferencing and mosaicking jpeg images using ArcMap with unknown spatial reference?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing, mosaic, raster-dataset

I have a series of large scale (almost 1:1), aerial jpeg images taken from a UAV DJI-FC350 drone camera. They have no spatial reference, but the images have their own GPS tags giving a single lat, lon and altitude for each.

I am trying to see if it is possible to use ArcMap to load them as raster datasets and mosaic them together to create a single image with the proper spatial locality.

I have read in some places that this might not be possible and you must use a photo stitching program to get a single image.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  What happens when you try to do this?  If it just works, then you will be able to self-answer.  If not, tell us precisely what you tried, and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to do this task in any GIS software. What you need is a software that uses the Structure-from-Motion algorithm. These are specialized photogrammetric software packages and the most popular are Pix4D and Agisoft Photoscan.